# Spotify API "No token provided" error code 401

Tags: python, spotify

While using Spotify API to extract user's top tracks, I've been receiving 401 error consistently. The code is shown below:

```py
import json
from requests import post, get
import base64

def get_token():
    auth_string = CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    } 

    data = {"grant_type" : "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

def searchArtist(token, artist_name):
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
    headers = {
        "Authorizations" : "Bearer " + token
    }
    query = f"?q={artist_name}&type=artist&limit=1"
    query_url = url + query
    result = get(query_url, headers=headers)
    data = result.json()
    print(data)

myToken = get_token()
searchArtist(myToken, "ACDC")
```

The following error is shown:

> {'error': {'status': 401, 'message': 'No token provided'}}

Am I missing something?

I was expecting the tracks to show. I've looked upon Spotify API docs and on my end I've been doing everything correctly. Probably I'm missing something or what is the actual, I can't tell.

Comment: Are `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` defined in the program because any placeholder values are not visible here. Is the token actually being returned from `get_token()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `searchArtist` you added `Authorizations` and it is not correct, it is `Authorization` without `s` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I have a following error:
```
def get_top_tracks(token):
    query_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks"
    header = {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
    }
    result = get(query_url, headers=header)
    print(result)
    
get_top_tracks(myToken)
```

The following code is resulting in <Response [403]>